# Is there a way to write to a memory stream, in a medium trust enviroment?

Tags: azure

I am working working on the early release of Azure from Microsoft and am not able to write to a memory stream. Keep getting an exception. I fixed the issue by using a different technique to achieve my end goal, however I wanted to know if there is a way to do it. Given that Azure is a shared infrastructure I cannot change the security level.

Comment: What error are you getting? mscorlib is marked with [AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers] and MemoryStream has no additional permission demands, so it should work find in a partial trust environment as long as you don't use the BeginX/EndX methods.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any medium trust issues with writing to a MemoryStream.  How are you writing to it?   What's the exception?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to reproduce it. I was doing it on the dev fabric of window's azure. Simply wanted to serialize an object to memory.